# Could have more then one form in jsp page?

Tags: jsp, forms

I need more then one form in a jsp page. Is it possible? Is this a good practice? And how can i do? Give me example.

Thanks.

Comment: The only system I've heard of which has problems with multiple forms with ASP.NET Webforms (since that shoves a massive form around the whole page, and you can't nest forms).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible as long as you don't nest them. This is not specifically a JSP restriction, but a HTML restriction (you know, all JSP does is outputting HTML/CSS/JS and all the webbrowser retrieves and understands is HTML/CSS/JS). It's certainly a good practice if those forms are not related to each other. E.g. a login form, a search form and a contact form in the same page.